# jQuery: How to append to list item, but before sublist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to use jQuery to append some content (it may be text or other elements) to the end of an item in an unordered list.  The item may contain a sub-list, so the content needs to appear *before* that sub-list.

My first instinct was to try:

```
$('li#someId').append(newContent);
```

Of course, if the item contained a sub-list, the new content appeared after that list.  I couldn't figure out a simple, all-purpose way to tell jQuery to append the content to the items, but before any sub-list.  I ended up writing this function to do it instead:

```
function appendBeforeSublist(listItem, content) {
    var sublist = listItem.find('ul:first');

    if (sublist.length > 0) {
        sublist.before(content);
    } else {
        listItem.append(content);
    }
}
```

It doesn't *feel* right, because I think there must be a more jQuery-like way of doing this.  How can I do this using just jQuery selectors and functions?  Also, is a more jQuery-like solution any better or worse, in terms of performance?  My code may perform this function a lot if the list is long.

For clarification, see [my experiment](http://jsfiddle.net/dE4HF/) in JSFiddle.

Comment: use listItem.prepend(content) to make the new content come before any content in listitem.

Comment: @keune: As the question says, I want to **append** content to the list item contents.  The exception is when the list item's contents includes another sub-list, then the content should appear before that.